# Java Impementing an interface. With additional functions

Tags: java, function, implements

Hello ive added two new functions to the implementation of an interface.

this is the implementation file...

```
import au.edu.uow.Collection.Album;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CDAlbum implements Album {
    private String Title;
    private String Genre;
    private String Artist;
    private String MediaType;
    private ArrayList<String> trackList;

    public CDAlbum(String TempTitle, String TempGenre, String TempArtist, ArrayList<String> TempTracklist, String TempMediaType){
        //Set initail variable values
        Title = TempTitle;
        Genre = TempGenre;
        Artist = TempArtist;
        trackList = TempTracklist;
        MediaType = TempMediaType;
    }
    //Accessor Functions
    public String getMediaType(){
        //Return Media Type
        return MediaType;
    }
    public String getTitle(){
        //Return Title
        return Title;
    }
    public String getGenre(){
        //Return Genre
        return Genre;
    }
    public String getArtist(){
        //Return Artist
        return Artist;
    }
    public ArrayList<String> getTrackList(){
        //Return Tracklist
        return trackList;
    }
}
```

The bottom two functions are the added functions( getArtist(), getTrackList())
the problem im having is that when i try to call these functions from a class file it give me the following errors.

```
./au/edu/uow/UserInterface/UserInterface.java:95: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getArtist()
location: interface au.edu.uow.Collection.Album
            System.out.println(albumCollection.get(number).getArtist());
                                                          ^
./au/edu/uow/UserInterface/UserInterface.java:98: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getTrackList()
location: interface au.edu.uow.Collection.Album
            ArrayList<String> trackList = albumCollection.get(number).getTrackList();
```

When i call the functions

```
import au.edu.uow.Collection.Album;

System.out.println(albumCollection.get(number).getArtist());

//Access the track titles
ArrayList<String> trackList = albumCollection.get(number).getTrackList();
//Output collection
int arrayListSize = trackList.size();
for(int i = 0; i < arrayListSize; i++)
{
    System.out.println( i + ": " + trackList.get(i));
}
```

Comment: could you show us your interface `Album` as well?! Seems these methods are missing in there.

Comment: provide the code of Album  class

Comment: @DanielDC `Album` specifies neither `getArtist` nor `getTrackList`, only `CDAlbum` does. You can determine whether the `Album` is a `CDAlbum` or `DVDAlbum` by checking `Album.getMediaType`; then, if it *is* a CD, you can cast to `CDAlbum` and invoke `getArtist` and `getTrackList` then.

Comment: I think Album is a super of CDAlbum or DVDAlbum interface. pls provide CDAlbum Interface

Comment: @MohammodHossain `Album` is an interface which `CDAlbum` and `DVDAlbum` implement.

Comment: reckoning by your package - university of wollongong student ?

Comment: @tito yes I believe so, I've seen several people asking about this same assignment on SO. I think it's due in a few hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Album` specifies neither `getArtist` nor `getTrackList`:

```
public interface Album {
    /**
     * This method returns the media type of the album. 
     * @return the media type of the album, either CD or DVD
     * @see #getTitle()
     * @see #getGenre()
     */
     String getMediaType();

    /**
     * This method returns the title of the album. 
     * @return the title of the album
     * @see #getMediaType()
     * @see #getGenre()
     */
     String getTitle();

    /**
     * This method returns the genre of the album. 
     * @return the genre of the album
     * @see #getTitle()
     * @see #getMediaType()
     */
    String getGenre();

}
```

... only `CDAlbum` does.

You can determine whether the `Album` is a `CDAlbum` or `DVDAlbum` by checking `Album.getMediaType`; then, if it *is* a CD, you can cast to `CDAlbum` and invoke `getArtist` and `getTrackList` then.

```
for (final Album album : albumCollection) {
  final String type = album.getMediaType();
  System.out.print(type + " album: " + album.getTitle()
      + " (" + album.getGenre() + ") - ");
  if (type.equals("CD")) {
    final CDAlbum cd = (CDAlbum) album;
    System.out.println(cd.getArtist());
    int n = 0;
    for (final String track : cd.getTrackList()) {
      System.out.printf("#%2d - %s\n", ++n, track);
    }
  } else {
    final DVDAlbum dvd = (DVDAlbum) album;
    System.out.println(dvd.getDirector());
    System.out.println(dvd.getPlotOutline());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add new method in your interface you must implement in your implementation class.

check the type of albumCollection.get(number)
if albumCollection.get(number)  return Album then you can call getArtist()

Comment: you mean i have to declare it in the interface ? is there another method so that i can just at it to the interface class?

Answer (score 0):

Is Album the return type of albumCollection.get(number)? If so, then you need to add getArtist and getTrackList method into your interface as well.

Comment: then albumCollection.get(number) return type should be CDAlbum. However, that would kill the whole point of having an interface.

Comment: can i just make the variables public and get them to print like that

Comment: Nope because Album doesn't know anything about CDAlbum. CDAlbum is an album but Album is not a CDAlbum.

Answer (score 0):

Create a super class say for example `MasterAlbums` and extend your `CDAlbum` and `DVDAlbum` from it.Place the methods `getArtist()` & `getTrackList()` in the super class.Do not override it in the subclasses.Now when you call `System.out.println(albumCollection.get(number).getArtist());` , It will refer to the superclass method and your artist & tracklist will be printed.